# Changing size of address field within table environment in html

Tags: html, input, html-table

I'm new to html. I have a project in which I have been asked to align the labels in the fieldset element. That is why I'm using the table environment. Probably because of that, if I try to set the size of the address field using rows and cols, there is no change. I have the following code:

```html
<fieldset class="">
  <legend>Your Contact information</legend>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <label for="mail"></label>
      <td align="right">Email: </td>
      <td align="left"><input type="email" name="mail" id= "mail" value="" required>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <label for="mob"></label>
      <td align="right">Mobile: </td>
      <td align="left"><input type="tel" name="mob" id = "mob" value="">
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <label for="add"></label>
      <td align="right">Address:  </td>
      <td align="left"><input type="textarea" rows = "4" cols = "20" name="add" id = "add" value="">
    </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the below sample I corrected a few issues, where having a `label` as a direct child of a `tr` is not allowed, the `input` doesn't have a type of `textarea` so I switched to a `<textarea></textarea>`, which will be passed along with the rest `input` fields during a submit of a form.

May I suggest you use the property `width` instead of `cols` when setting the width of a textarea. With that you can more easily match it with the input fields making it look better.

```css
.contactinfo {
  background:lightyellow;
  border:10px solid yellow;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  width: 720px;
}
.contactinfo input,
.contactinfo textarea {
  width: 180px;
  box-sizing: border-box;    /* have border/padding included in the given width */
}
.contactinfo td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="contactinfo">
  <legend>Your Contact information</legend>
  <table>
    <tr>      
      <td align="right"><label for="mail">Email: </label></td>
      <td align="left"><input type="email" name="mail" id= "mail" value="" required>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right"><label for="mob">Mobile: </label></td>
      <td align="left"><input type="tel" name="mob" id = "mob" value="">
    </tr>
    <tr>      
      <td align="right"><label for="add">Address: </label></td>
      <td align="left"><textarea rows = "4" name="add" id = "add"></textarea>
    </tr>
  </table>
</fieldset>
```

Using a `div` as a wrapper instead, it will allow more options in a responsive layout.

```css
.contactinfo {
  background:lightyellow;
  border:10px solid yellow;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  width: 720px;
}
.contactinfo label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align:top;
}
.contactinfo div ~ div {
  margin-top: 2px;
}
.contactinfo input,
.contactinfo textarea {
  width: 180px;
  box-sizing: border-box;    /* have border/padding included in the given width */
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="contactinfo">
  <legend>Your Contact information</legend>
  <div>
    <label for="mail">Email: </label>
    <input type="email" name="mail" id= "mail" value="" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="mob">Mobile: </label>
    <input type="tel" name="mob" id = "mob" value="">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="add">Address: </label>
    <textarea rows = "4" name="add" id = "add"></textarea>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: How can I include [code](background:lightyellow; border:10px solid yellow; margin-bottom:10px; width: 720px) into the style class contactinfo? I tried using - [code](.contactinfo fieldset{background:lightyellow; border:10px solid yellow; margin-bottom:10px; width: 720px;}) but doesn't change anything.

Comment: @user3922546 Updated my answer. When you use `.contactinfo fieldset` you are saying, _set this rule to an element with class `.contantinfo` who has a `fieldset` as a child_, ... you should use only `.contactinfo`

Answer (score 1):

Your can not use a textarea as a input type

```
<input type="textarea" rows = "4" cols = "20" name="add" id = "add" value="">
```

You should edit this like this

```
<textarea col="4" rows="25" name="add" id = "add"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```html
<fieldset class="">
      <legend>Your Contact information</legend>
      <table width="100%">
        <tr>
          <label for="mail"></label>
          <td align="right">Email: </td>
          <td align="left"><input type="email" name="mail" id= "mail" value="" required>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <label for="mob"></label>
          <td align="right">Mobile: </td>
          <td align="left"><input type="tel" name="mob" id = "mob" value="">
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <label for="add"></label>
          <td align="right">Address:  </td>
          <td align="left"><textarea rows = "4" cols = "20" name="add" id = "add" value=""></textarea>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use CSS to resize them.

```
 <tr>
  <label for="mail"></label>
  <td align="right">Email: </td>
  <td align="left"><input type="email" name="mail" id= "mail" style="width:200px; height:200px;" value="" required>
</tr>
```

This should work.